# Is there a utility that will greate an iPhone screenshot with hardware and reflection?

Tags: iphone, graphics

I need to take screen shots of my iPhone app and load it on a web site. I know how to get the raw image of the screen but I was wondering if there is a utility out there that can take a screen shot and add the hardware image too?

Comment: do you mean what I think you mean my hardware image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [iOS Simulator Cropper](http://www.curioustimes.de/iphonesimulatorcropper/).

Comment: I got it, this tool is awesome! Thanks!